# Is there a plugin to trigger a Jenkins build when a specific Github file changes?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, github-pages

I am trying to create a Jenkins build trigger, with [FSTrigger]- Monitor files.
File path added to monitor a file change on a specific Github file: https://github.com/path/to/file/check.json
Schedule for running the FSTrigger monitoring : * * * * * (to run every minute)

Getting the following error in 'FSTrigger Files Log' on the left of Jenkins job: 
"Polling on master.
The folder path 'https://github.com/path/to/file' doesn't exist.
The computed file doesn't exist.
Polling complete. Took 2 ms.
No changes."

Is FSTrigger plugin on Jenkins not supporting monitoring a Github file change? Please let me know your suggestions.